# HTTPS Tomcat setup

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat7, tomcat5.5

I am trying to configure https in my tomcat. I have gone through many blogs and generated key store file and added the following tag in the server.xml.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
              connectionTimeout="20000" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
              clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="../webapps/easwarkey.bin" keystorePass="easwar"/>
```

Also I left the tag with 8081 port as it is.

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

But when i start the server. I can able to see the home page of the tomcat @ http://localhost:8081/

But nothing @ https://localhost:8443

Could you please mention what has to be done other than this.

Thanks in advance, Easwar

Comment: Could you also provide us with Tomcat logs (catalina.out, localhost*.log)?

Comment: What exactly is "nothing" at the https port? Connection error, certificate error, just nothing in the browser? I'd also like to see a logfile

Comment: Nothing means no webpage available. I dont find any connection or certificate error.

Comment: Hi Everyone. I solved the issue.. Actually its my mistake that my file path of the key store was wrong. Thanks for you interest and comment.

Comment: try 443 port instead of 8443, may be that can help.